# Testing functions in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I need some advice on testing functions in terms of how and what

say I have some state.

```
state = {
  categories: [this is full of objects],
  products: [this is also full of objects]
}
```

then I have this function:

```
  filterProducts = () => {
    return this.state.products.filter((product => (
      product.categories.some((cat) => (
         cat.title == this.state.chosenCategory
      ))
    )))
  }
```

this function filters the products array by working out if the products are part of the selected category.

how would you test this?

I've tried this

```
 let productsStub = [
    {id: 1, title: 'wine01', showDescription: false},
    {id: 2, title: 'wine02', showDescription: false},
    {id: 3, title: 'wine03', showDescription: false}
  ]
  wrapper = shallow(<Menu
    categories={categoriesStub}
    products={productsStub}
    />);


  it('should filter products when searched for', () => {
    const input = wrapper.find('input');
    input.simulate('change', {
      target: { value: '01' }
    });
    expect(productsStub.length).toEqual(1);
  });
```

what this test (I think) is saying, when I search for 01, I expect the product state (well the stub of the state) to filter and return only 1 result. however the test fails and says expected: 1 received: 3 i.e. the filtering isn't working.

I know I could also do `wrapper.instance.filterProducts()` but again, I'm not very comfortable on function testing in jest.

any advice? would be great to chat it through with someone

thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could provide code in https://codesandbox.io/ or some other tool, so we can talk about it.

Comment: @ChasingUnicorn what more code do you want sorry? It's just a function that filters the state array and im wondering how to test that..?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your problem statement, but not sure how are you maintaining the state model (props/state). But this might help. :)

Checkout the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6zw0krx15k

```
import React from "react";

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: [{ id: 1 }],
    products: this.props.products,
    selectedCat: 1,
    filteredProducts: []
  };

  filterProducts = value => {
    let filteredVal = this.props.products.filter(
      product => product.id === parseInt(value)
    );

    this.setState({
      filteredProducts: filteredVal
    });
  };

  setValue = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedCat: e.target.value
    });
    this.filterProducts(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Filter
        <input value={this.state.selectedCat} onChange={this.setValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Filter from "./Filter";
import React from "react";


let productsStub = [
  { id: 1, title: "wine01", showDescription: false },
  { id: 2, title: "wine02", showDescription: false },
  { id: 3, title: "wine03", showDescription: false }
];
let wrapper = shallow(<Filter products={productsStub} />);

it("should filter products when searched for", () => {
  const input = wrapper.find("input");
  input.simulate("change", {
    target: { value: "1" }
  });
  expect(wrapper.state().filteredProducts.length).toEqual(1);
});
```